# How to use hubspot to track code to see page visitors and clicks

Tags: php, hubspot

I need to install a HubSpot tracking code to keep track of site visitors on a PHP website. How do I set up HubSpot tracking on my site?

I am completely new for HubSpot . :(

Comment: Hubspot sets a cookie hubspotutk you can use that to track. If you can be more specific in what you need exactly, I can help a bit. I have used it before.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for reply mate. I need to find out page visitors and page visit count using hubspot, probably a method to develop an api for that one.

Comment: HUbspot provides a script to add to page which generates a unique id and adds it to cookie. DO you have that?

Comment: Yes i do have that one.

Comment: I need to find out page visitors and page visit count using hubspot - so u need to track all visitors, all pages they visit and which page they visit how many times? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: yes. you are absolutely right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35069/discussion-between-abani-meher-and-ays)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am running into the same problem :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

After logging into your HubSpot account at https://login.hubspot.com/login/, you're tracking snippet can be found under the "Reports" dropdown and then "Reports Settings".

Paste this snippet on all pages of your marketing site before the closing  tag.

Answer (score 0):

The HubSpot tracking code will automatically record a page view when the code is first loaded, but you can also manually track page views in a single-page application without reloading the tracking code. You can use the setPath and trackPageView functions to update and track the current page:

```
<!-- Set up the path for the initial page view -->
<script>
  var _hsq = window._hsq = window._hsq || [];
  _hsq.push(['setPath', '/home']);
</script>

<!-- Load the HubSpot tracking code -->
<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/{hubId}.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->

<!-- Tracking subsequent page views -->
<script>
  var _hsq = window._hsq = window._hsq || [];
  _hsq.push(['setPath', '/about-us']);
  _hsq.push(['trackPageView']);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the tracking code to a JS file that is loaded on all your pages (e.g. main.js, common.js, etc...). See here: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/reports/install-the-hubspot-tracking-code

You can also add the HubSpot JS tag to Google Tag Manager, which will automatically include it on your website if you have the GTag already there.